# "Circulant-Vandermonde" matrix: in search of a formula

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, linear-algebra, cv.complex-variables, determinants

An $n\times n$ [*circulant matrix*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulant_matrix) $\mathbf{X}_n$ has the form

\begin{align}
\mathbf{X}_n= \begin{bmatrix} 
x_1 & x_2 & \cdots & x_{n-1} & x_n \\ 
x_2 & x_3 & \cdots & x_n& x_1 \\ 
\vdots & \vdots& \ddots & \vdots & \vdots \\ 
x_{n-1} &x_n & \cdots & x_{n-3} & x_{n-2} \\ 
x_n & x_1 & \cdots & x_{n-2} & x_{n-1} \\ \end{bmatrix}. 
\end{align}
If $f(z)=x_1+x_2z+\dotsb+x_{n-1}z^{n-2}+x_nz^{n-1}$ and $\xi=e^{\frac{2\pi i}n}$ with $i=\sqrt{-1}$ then we've the determinant
$$\det(\mathbf{X}_n)=\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}f(\xi^k).\tag1\label1$$
For example, $\det(\mathbf{X}_1)=x_1$, $\det(\mathbf{X}_2)=x_1^2-x_2^2$,
$\det(\mathbf{X}_3)=x_1^3+ x_2^3 + x_3^3-3x_1x_2x_3$ and
\begin{align}
\det(\mathbf{X}_4)
&=x_1^4-x_2^4+x_3^4-x_4^4-4x_1^2x_2x_4+4x_1x_2^2x_3+4x_1x_3x_4^2- 4x_2x_3^2x_4 \\
&\,\,\, \qquad -2x_1^2x_3^2+2x_2^2x_4^2.\end{align}
I like to change this a little bit to the matrix $\widetilde{\mathbf{X}}_n$ given by
\begin{align}
\widetilde{\mathbf{X}}_n= \begin{bmatrix} 
x_1 & x_2 & \cdots & x_{n-1} & x_n \\ 
x_2^2 & x_3^2 & \cdots & x_n^2& x_1^2 \\ 
\vdots & \vdots& \ddots & \vdots & \vdots \\ 
x_{n-1}^{n-1} &x_n^{n-1} & \cdots & x_{n-3}^{n-1} & x_{n-2}^{n-1} \\ 
x_n^n & x_1^n & \cdots & x_{n-2}^n & x_{n-1}^n \\ \end{bmatrix}. 
\end{align}
For example, $\det(\widetilde{\mathbf{X}}_1)=x_1$, $\det(\widetilde{\mathbf{X}}_2)=x_1^3-x_2^3$ and
$$\det(\widetilde{\mathbf{X}}_3)= x_1^6+x_2^6+x_3^6-x_1^3x_2x_3^2-x_1^2x_2^3x_3-x_1x_2^2x_3^3.$$
In view of these and more examples, there seem to be some structure, so I would like to ask:

> **QUESTION.** Is there a formula for $\det(\widetilde{\mathbf{X}}_n)$ similar to that of \eqref{1}?

Comment: Not sure what one can say from three examples. What do you mean by more experimentation? What did it reveal? Do you expect a nice answer merely because of the circulant case? In fact, why stop at the Vandermonde determinant. Take alternants with exponents of the form $\lambda_i+n-i$.

Comment: Sure that these are beautiful cyclic patterns. But if even for $n=3$, the determinant doesn't seem to allow any kind of decomposition and the [discriminant](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Polynomial+discriminant+of+%28x%5E6%2Bx_2%5E6%2Bx_3%5E6-x%5E3x_2x_3%5E2-x%5E2x_2%5E3x_3-x_2%5E2x_3%5E3x%29) is as it is, there won't be a lot of hope. Unless you can find "nice" eigenvectors, but even for e.g. $(x_1,x_2,x_3)=(1,2,4)$ there is nothing nice... :(

Comment: If I were tasked with understanding this, I'd use the UFD-ness of $\mathbb Z[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ and/or $\mathbb C[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$, and make adroit choices of values of the $x$'s to get vanishing, ... much as we do for Vandermonde.